# Screen orientation change calls unexpected viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, viewdidload

I have an application with two view controllers, namely `vc1` and `vc2`. I also have a navigation controller on top of them. I want `vc1` to be in portrait orientation and `vc2` to be in landscape right orientation. For this, I use the following code `vc1`:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

and following for `vc2`:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Here is what I do:

1. App launches with `vc1` in portrait orientation.
2. With a button click in `vc1`, I navigate to `vc2`.
3. `vc2` screen rotates to lansdcape right orientation.

Everything is normal until here, then I go back to the `vc1` using the back button of the navigation controller, this triggers `viewDidLoad` of `vc2`. Why is this happening? I'm going back to `vc1` how can `vc2` get loaded again?

**Note 1:** This behaviour does not happen if both screens are in same orientation (portrait or landscape).

**Note 2:** I don't think that this problem is about how I set the orientation. Because I tried using `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, and I can say that, if the orientations of `vc1` and `vc2` are different, when I go back to `vc1` from `vc2`, viewDidLoad in `vc2` runs.

Comment: Setting the `orientation` property of `UIDevice` is not supported.

Comment: @Rengers What do you mean by _not supported_? It sets the orientation successfully. Besides, as I mentioned in the **Note 2**, even if I don't use `orientation` property of `UIDevice` and use `supportedInterfaceOrientations` or any other function, I can set the orientation successfully. No matther which approach I use, if previous view controller has different orientation, `viewDidLoad` of the current view controller runs. That is my problem.

Comment: Although it works using KVC, the `orientation` property is documented as read-only: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/orientation. It is only meant to be read, the system internally updates it when the user rotates the device. That is probably why you are seeing weird behavior.

Comment: @Rengers ok I will stop using it. But this does not solve my problem. Even if I don't use it, I'm facing the same issue anyways.